# How to find an exe file is a zip SFX file, C#?

Tags: c#, zip, sfx

In `WinRar` or `7Zip` or ... we have a choice to convert zip file to an exe file(SFX).
Now,
How can we find, if `SomeFile.exe` is a SFX file or not?
**Note:**
This file can created by any zip applications.

Answer (score 1):

I found only one, but not good variant. But better than nothing. You can create all variants SFX files and pull unique service data (bytes array) from them, and check .exe files for this data. For example for my 7z SFX:

[image]

Comment: I created a 7ZIP SFX file with latest version of 7ZIP 15.12, I didn't see some thing like you in hex view of it. !!!

Comment: @MohammadDayyan You are right, I have updated 7Z and didn't find this data too. Try use EXE file properties. I think this variant can be better. System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path).FileDescription . For 7z result will be "7z SFX"

Comment: 7zip files have some information in `GetVersionInfo` but `WinRar` doesn't write anything in Version Info. So we can't use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at offset `0x1C` (reserved bytes) in your exe file (but first check for `MZ` at the beginning of the file).

See [here](http://www.fileformat.info/format/exe/corion-mz.htm) for some examples.